# python classify predictions

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have used sklearn in python to read an excel sheet and predict a group names based on its description. The next step i want to take is grouping similar groups. I am not sure which method will best satisfy what i'm attempting to do.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np

path = 'data/mydata.csv'
exp = pd.read_csv(path, names=['group_name', 'description'])

X = exp.description
y = exp.group_name
fixed_X = X[pd.notnull(X)]
fixed_y = y[pd.notnull(y)]

vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
nb = MultinomialNB()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(fixed_X, fixed_y, 
random_state=1)
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)

nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
y_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred_class))
```

This prints the accuracy of the predicted groups, which is what i want. How do i group similar 'group_names' based on the data and predictions provided?

Desired output(based on predictions and data behind it)

```
if there are 10 groups total
group 1: [group_name1, group_name5,group_name10]
group 2: [group_name2, group_name4]
group 3: [group_name3, group_name6, group_name7, group_name9]
group 4: [group_name10]
```

(the number of groups wont matter shouldn't matter, i just want the correct group_names, with similar group_names all in one group.
or

a visual model which shows a clustering of all group names

Comment: What do you mean by "group similar groups"?

Comment: I mean i want to group similar 'group_names' based on the data, and the predictions it has made.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you would like?

Comment: @Evan see above edit

Comment: Please forgive my unfamiliarity with the subject matter, but if you're trying to classify groups into groups of groups, wouldn't that be data-dependent? Based upon what criteria does one decide how similar two (or n) groups are?

Comment: yes it would. and based on the code i posted, the its doing predictions based on the data-'descriptions'- im giving it through an excel file. Since it can make predictions i want it to group similar 'group names'

Comment: Maybe you need this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html